# Linux LDAP query to AD : missing group members

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Two different Linux servers (CentOS & Ubuntu) on my LAN cannot see certain members of an AD group when performing an LDAP query.

We're setting up a software appliance which can use LDAP for authentication.  To limit the number of internal users that can access the appliance, I created a 'filetransfer' group in our AD and added 8 users to it.

I have tried performing the following LDAP query with CentOS 6.5 and Ubuntu 12.04.4:

```
   ldapsearch \
     "(memberof=CN=FileTransfer,OU=Security Groups,DC=domain,DC=local)" \
     dn -x -W -D 'cn=ldapquery,ou=user accounts,dc=domain,dc=local' -LLL
```

And here are the results:

```
dn: CN=Eva ,OU=User Accounts,DC=domain,DC=Local
dn: CN=Simon ,OU=User Accounts,DC=domain,DC=Local
dn: CN=Eric ,OU=User Accounts,DC=domain,DC=Local
dn: CN=Ronald ,OU=User Accounts,DC=domain,DC=Local

# refldap://ForestDnsZones.domain.Local/DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=domain,DC=Local
# refldap://DomainDnsZones.domain.Local/DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=domain,DC=Local
# refldap://domain.Local/CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=Local
```

The AD group contains 8 members, but the LDAP query is only returning 4.

I have deleted and recreated the group; no joy.

I have added new test user accounts to the group and they don't show up even after leaving things over the weekend.

I know that the domain is syncing properly, because as soon as I remove one of the 'visible' users - the LDAP query reflects the change on both Linux servers.

Can anyone explain this weirdness?

Comment: These are direct group members, not nested?  Also, those accounts aren't configured with that group as the 'Primary' group?

Answer (score 2):

Correct.  These are direct group members - not nested.

A temporary solution to my problem is to use an administrative account to do the LDAP query.

Somehow certain AD objects were not readable by the generic account I was using (the LDAP query account did not have the `read group membership` permission) - adding that right to my generic LDAP query account fixed the issue permanently.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is not just Linux LDAP queries to Active Directory.  Also occurs with Java LDAP and Powershell AD queries.  In these cases as well, for certain AD users, could not query the **member of** attribute and get any results.  Again, the account being used for the query did not have the **read group membership** permission on the AD users in question.

For example, querying for the user "ptest" with AD as follows gives no results if the querying user does not have the right permissions on the user "ptest".  (Otherwise would normally get a number of lines beginning with "CN" showing groups that "ptest" belongs to).

```
Get-ADUser ptest -Properties * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf
```